# Case Assignment Rules cause permissions error for User, but Case is still created

Tags: case, permissions, error, assignment-rules

Our Salesforce system has a private OWD for the Case object, with access opened up via Owner-Based Sharing Rules, Case Teams & the Role Hierarchy. We recently implemented assignment rules to start assigning Cases to queues. Users are now **sometimes** getting this error when they try to create a new Case:

[image]

After some investigation, it seems like the Case Assignment rules are causing this (turning them off makes the error go away). I can only assume the cause is that the assignment rules are making the creator lose access to the record.

Here's the weird part... **The Case is still created** in the background even if they receive this error! This has led to lots of Case duplication by Users because they keep retrying and getting the error. This seems very odd to me.

**Has anyone experienced this before? Can anyone explain this behaviour?**

**My best guess at what's happening:**  Users are allowed to create the record, and then the assignment rules cause the User to lose access to it, which then prevents Salesforce from taking the User to view the record. Still, I would expect to be taken to the record, and just blocked from seeing it. I wouldn’t have expected an error to appear on the create screen, which makes it seem like the record was not created. Doesn't seem like expected behaviour??

Comment: Is the error only for particular user?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala No, it's for all users, but only when they try create a Case which is going to be assigned to a different unit/team (i.e. they won't have access to the case after the assignment rules run)

Comment: Did you compare the debug logs using assignment rules and with out assignment rules active?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala yea I can do that, but before I try dig any deeper I would like someone to validate whether the scenario described is EXPECTED behaviour. Because if so, then there's nothing further to troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't think this is something expected behavior.

Comment: @JustinF: Is there a after insert trigger/flow which is again updating something in the case causing this error ? The error on the UI indicates Case is being updated in the context of the user. Also , a related article - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389087&type=1
Can you try the same operation in Classic as per the article?

Comment: @Rohit thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for - proof that this is expected behaviour and just very poor error handling design from Salesforce. I've created a Case and logged an idea on the IdeaExchange to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, thanks to @Rohit in the comments it seems like [this is expected/known behaviour](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389087&type=1) and just really bad error handling design by Salesforce.

My temporary fix has been to create a screen flow which runs from a custom list view button and ensures that the User is told very clearly that the Case WAS submitted but they may no longer have access to it.

I have posted [an idea on the IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000O2GX4UAN/fix-poor-error-handling-when-user-loses-access-to-case-after-creating-record) to fix this. Please upvote it!

Comment: Great! You can use a flow to insert Apex sharing as well to grant access for the case.

Comment: @Rohit absolutely! Just need to confirm with Stakeholders if the original Case submitter SHOULD get access to the Case after submitting :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because case is assigned into Queue suddenly once after created. Actually the creation record page trying to show the created case record into that user but created user of the case record is lost his access(due to case assigned into Queue via Case assignment rule). So it's cause error due to case's **OWD settings** is configured as `Private` and after that case record is assigned into Queue **the Queue member(s) is only able to access that created case not that created user**.

Now, please create a custom logic in flow as follows to maintain previous case created user's access to fix this issue.

- Once case is assigned into Queue, Create a case team member (via flow) for that Case and add that created user is a case team member with `Read Only` access. (Note: It's only allow to view that case record for that case owner)
- If case created user need to edit once after Case assigned into Queue means, add the case created user as into Case team member with `Read/Write` access.

*Note: Please Choose the case created user's access based on your requirement from above 2 options.*

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I agree that lack of access is the most likely reason for this error, but I am still surprised that it presents the same way a validation rule error does, which makes Users think that the Case was not submitted (but it was), which in turn leads to them retrying a couple of times and creating duplicate Cases. I would expect that they should be taken to a new page and be told very clearly "Your record was created but you do not have access to it anymore".

Comment: As for your solution idea... Unfortunately you cannot add a Queue (the Owner) as a Case Team Member. It also wouldn't solve my problem because the person creating the Case is not in the Queue that the Case is being assigned to... that's why they are receiving a permissions error. It might be feasible to add the Case creator (not Owner) as a Case Team Member (I'm discussing this with stakeholders), but I suspect that might not solve the permissions error either, due to the order of excecution and when Salesforce evaluates permissions.

Comment: @JustinF Sorry to make you confuse. What I am trying to say is case owner as "Case's created user". Thanks for point out. I will update my answer which doesn't confuse anyone further.